# Updating cloud firestore data in a map from flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code:

```
child: new GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    children: snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        return new MoodButton(
            iconData: (IconData(document.data()['ref'],fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
            onTap: () =>
                document.data()[document.data()['ref']].updateData({"display": true}),
        );
     }).toList(),
)
```

I am trying to update the value of `display` for the icon that has been clicked on from false to true.
The issue is with the line `document.data()[document.data()['ref']].updateData({"Display": true}),`. I am not sure how to update the data for the specific icon that has been clicked on.
The error I am getting is:

```
The method 'updateData' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: updateData(_LinkedHashMap len:1)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6c0R6pcbU8&list=PLgGjX33Qsw-Ha_8ks9im86sLIihimuYrr&index=9) tutorial.

I replaced `onTap: () => document.data()[document.data()['ref']].updateData({"display": true}),` with `onTap: () => updateData((document.data()['name']), {'display' : true}),`

Then added

```
updateData(selectedDoc, newValues) {
    print(selectedDoc);
    print(newValues);
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('icons')
          .doc(selectedDoc)
          .update(newValues)
          .catchError((e) {
        print(e);
      });
    }
```